# iOS Push Notification big payloads on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

With iOS8 Apple has increased the allowed payload size for push notifications to 2K.
What will happen if I send the same push notification to iOS7? How will it behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payload size limit concerns the server only, so I believe the iOS7 devices will handle it as usual (in launchOptions or didReceiveRemoteNotification:).

Comment: The payload size increase was and improvement on Apple's side. iOS 7 device will receive the push notifications as usual.

Comment: @godmoney Have you tried it in production? The documentation says the exact opposite, but then again, it could be wrong...

Comment: @Michal Where does it say in the documentation the exact opposite?

Comment: Exactly where I pointed out in my answer - it clearly says **(Prior to iOS 8 and in OS X, the maximum payload size is 256 bytes.)** - there is **is** and not **was**, so it feels like iOS 7 won't even now accept anything higher than 256 bytes. Again, I haven't tried it in production, so it may not be relevant, but it sure seems like it.

Comment: Searching around I've found comments saying that tests with payload > 256 bytes are received by iOS7 devices normally. 
I think posts like this confirm it:
https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs/pull/79#issuecomment-51021572

Too bad that the documentation is so slowly updated...

Comment: @Vrasidas Alright, good to know! I'm deleting my answer in order not to confuse any newcomers to this question. I'd raise a flag, but I suppose reasons such as "update documentation" will just fall into a pit in Apple's flag pipeline...